# игнор условия в таймере формы С# (WIN FORMS) VS2015

Tags: c#, компиляция, if

Есть скрытая форма, на ней таймер, который срабатывает 1 раз в секунду, (это не вирус или воровайка какая), а программа, которая будет отслеживать новые файлы на **ftp** и загружать на рабочий компьютер, небольшая автоматизация рутины.

Код вроде как простой, но условие НЕ выполняется (в окне редактора, там где указаны строки, подчеркнут желтым цветом, "что это за..." - не знаю).

Стоит скинуть под условие **MessageBox**, все работает.

```
int ids = 0;

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ids = ids + 1;
    MessageBox.Show("я работаю!" + ids.ToString());
    if (ids == 2)
    {
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Укажите в метках язык программирования.

Comment: WinForms или WPF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по всему, происходит следующее. Вызывается первый тик таймера, увеличивает `ids` до 1 и показывает `MessageBox`. Теперь код «висит» в функции `Show()`.

Пока `MessageBox` открыт, проходит несколько секунд. Тем временем приходит второй тик таймера, увеличивает `ids` до 2 и показывает второй `MessageBox`.

Так же случается и с третьим, возможно четвёртым. Когда вы наконец закрываете все `MessageBox`'ы, значение `ids` уже стало большим. Условие `ids == 2` больше не выполняется.

---

Когда вы заносите `MessageBox.Show` внутрь `if`'а, проверка выполняется *до* ожидания закрытия `MessageBox`'а, и всё работает как и ожидалось.

Comment: Вы мне помогли действительно (ids == 2) заменил на (ids > 2) и поместил MessageBox.Show в блок else. Вот только очередность выполнения кода меня с толку сбивает, подскажите где подробней почитать про это?

Comment: а ведь точно! Стоит поменять `MessageBox.Show` на `Console.WriteLine` и проверить еще раз

Comment: @Дмитрий, а вы попробуйте перед показом сообщения отключать таймер, а потом включать

Comment: @Дмитрий: Ещё имеет смысл внутри блока остановить таймер

Comment: @Андрей: Лучше по идее просто остановить, т. к. у ТС условие является условием завершения.

Comment: @VladD, ну у него выход по условию. Если условие не сработало, надо запустить (или не надо, ТС видней)

Comment: @Андрей: Я имел в виду, в дополнение к перемещению показа диалога внутрь условия или вообще удаления его (диалог-то всё равно лишь для отладки, кому хочется видеть по модальному диалогу каждую секунду?).